# ESP32-S2 as USB keyboard

Tags: keyboard, usb, emulation, esp32

I need help to understand how I can emulate a keyboard using the ESP32-S2. I'm new with this device. I'm able to compile [this example](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/api-reference/peripherals/usb.html).

The problem that I have is that I found a lot of examples for Arduino: these examples import these libraries:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "hidkeyboard.h"
```

But in the Espressif esp-idf these libraries are not available.

So, how can I use [this code](https://github.com/chegewara/EspTinyUSB/blob/master/examples/hid/keyboard2/keyboard2.ino) in order to be compiled by esp-idf? Thanks.

Comment: "hidkeyboard.h" is part of that same repository.  There are lots of places to get Arduino.h.  Have you googled for it?

Comment: Hi Tim,I followed this guide: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/get-started/index.html#step-4-set-up-the-environment-variables, and I'm able to compile it, but I don't know how to 'add' arduino.h in the esp-idf. Can you help me?

Comment: Your project is pulling include files from many locations.  "arduino.h" just needs to be in one of them.  I don't know the layout of their folders.

Answer (score 4):

Probably moderators didn't understand my answer and deleted my previous answer, so I will try to answer one more time.

You can't use that library with esp-idf as it was designed to work with Arduino only on ESP32-S2. There is an example how to use older versions of this library with esp-idf as Arduino as a component.

To moderators: my intention was not to promote myself when I posted a link to a Github repository, but I wanted to show how to use the library requested in the question with that particular hardware, also requested in the question.

Comment: Can you just include the example here?